# How to integrate i18next translation library in PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, internationalization, i18next

I have a codeigniter base website in English and I have to add two different language now.I tried to generate an example with the documentation on http://i18next.com but it seems I failed.I want to translate all custom attribute like input value and row datatable value into different language.

Is there any way to use i18next language translation in codeigniter?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.